Alternative PowerShell Solution To Running MDX on a Power Bi Semantic Model Hosted In A Fabric Workspace
So we want to do this, but it's not supported. So we must pursue a alternative solution. Optimally this would something that could be run from SQL Server directly with minimal external code possible.
I would like a powershell script that allows me to run a large MDX statement against a cube in a Fabric Workspace. I would like to be able to call that script directly from a T-SQL proc in SQL Server 2022 and would support the return of a result set consistent with the same cube running the same MDX statement on a traditional Analysis Service instance.(Same column names, formatting, etc..)
It's critical that this script supports MDX statements larger than 8000 characters and can return (and SQL Server can use) large result sets.
The initial research I've done indicates that this is a non-trivial challenge (see above link for the first problem), I'm not the first person to ask for this, but I haven't seen anything that does this directly. It would be nice to have a community contributed answer that other people could use, if there isn't one or if the community can't do this I will post my solution and allows other to improve upon it.

Something like sp_execute_external_script perhaps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-external-script-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 perhaps? This is if you want native resultsets. Otherwise i guess you can return a json from your powershell script and parse it yourself (either through xp_cmdshell or via sql agent job). You can also implement a CLR stored procedure or (the horror) ODS extended dll procedure

Do you want linked server to a semantic model, or a Fabric SQL Endpoint?

@DavidBrowne Semantic model(a cube basically...)

I would recommend using PowerShell.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-ascmd?view=sqlserver-ps But linked server is also possible.  The setup is a bit of a pain, because the OleDb provider needs to run out-of-process to do the Entra ID Authentication.
